# How to Add a UITextView to a UITableView Detail

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiviewcontroller

Need some help figuring out how to add some text (UITextView?) to a UITableView detail view. The screenshot shows a vacant white space where I need to add the UITextView.

Here is a screenshot of what I have:

[image: UITableView that needs a UITextView]

Here is the method where I am assigning the UITableView detail title value.

```
//MainViewControler.m
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
  UIViewController *detailsViewController = [[UIViewController alloc] init];


   // get detail view controller "title" value
   detailsViewController.title = word.term;



  [[self navigationController] pushViewController:detailsViewController animated:YES];
  [detailsViewController release];
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: You mean when you click on UITableView Cell, you get this page right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you create detailsViewController object, add the following code:

```
UITextView *txtView = [[UITextView alloc] init];
txtView.text = @"UITextView text";
txtView.frame = CGRectMake(0,0,320,100);
[detailsViewController.view addSubview:txtView];
[txtView release];
txtView = nil;
```

Answer (score 2):

If you get this page by clicking on the Previous TableView,
Then do the following for adding the UITextView:

1. Go to Interface Builder.
2. Put UITextView by dragging it to your view (current view, which you have shown in snapshot).
3. connect View's delegate to the file's owner.
4. You can add code from IB or at runtime in UITextView.

Hope, it helped.
Good luck.

Comment: Or you can put the code which cocoakomali wrote as answer, straight forward.

Comment: Thanks, that was helpful. I ended up creating the view in a programmatic way.

Comment: Good. That way is always preferable. As it makes things clear.

Answer (score 1):

```
UITextView *yourView =[[UITextView alloc] initWithFrame : CGRectMake(15,15,250,300)]autorelease]; // you can alter the frame values.

[detailsViewController.view addsubview : yourView]
```

I have added all this code from typing.. i can confirm its correct syntax..use autocomplete.